# Wordpress remove comment_form( 'cancel_reply_link' )?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Customizing my comment templates and I'm working with the `comment_form` function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

It seems easy enough to remove some things such as the text below the form that says "you may use these tags and attributes" and other things by overwritting the defaults with blank values. However it doesn't let you remove the `cancel_reply_link' from the template as removing its value from the array still makes it display the default.

```
<?php
    comment_form(
        array(
            'comment_notes_after'   => '',
            'title_reply'           => '',
            'comment_field'         => '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" placeholder="Leave a comment..."></textarea>',
            'logged_in_as'          => '',
            'cancel_reply_link'     => ''
        )
    );
?>
```

As you can see the `cancel_reply_link` is left empty, but it will still output the following HTML before my comment `textarea`.

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">
    <small>
        <a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/websites/wordpress/post-6/comment-page-1/#respond">Click here to cancel reply.</a>
    </small>
</h3>
```

How can i remove this `h3` and its content?

The reason I want it removed is so I can simply add a "cancel" button next to the "submit" button below the `textarea` when people are replying to others comments.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsjdi.png

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices here. One is to use css to conceal that element from your users.

```
h3.comment-reply-title { display: none)
```

The other choice might be to use the `'cancel_comment_reply_link'` filter to edit the html.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1549

Comment: Would rather remove it than hide it. I'll look at that file and see what I can come up with. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the cancel link you need to use wordpress built in `__return_false` function for returning false value for filters like this:

```
add_filter( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', '__return_false' );
```

This has already been answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/how-to-remove-the-click-here-to-cancel-reply-link-from-the-wordpress-comment-f).

The above function resides in wp-includes/functions.php:

```
function __return_false() {
    return false;
}
```

There are more similar functions returning common values for filters like: `__return_true` or `__return_empty_string` in wp-includes/functions.php

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you, guys for pointing that out. I have edited my answer. Please excuse my lack of knowledge, still a noob here.